# Embedded youtube Playlists do not work on iPad (iOS)

Tags: ios, html, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I am embedding a Youtube playlist and it works fine on normal desktop browsers, but on iPad it is not working. From the various questions here and some other info I read that Youtube is capable of detecting the client and serve an HTML5 version of the video instead. However, it seems that it works only for a single video URL. When I am using a playlist URL instead it does not work. I am using the `<frame>` embedding approach.

Is there any way to go around this? I can't seem to find any settings on the Youtube playlist to make it 'html5 friendly'.

Comment: Please read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757603/youtube-iframe-api-onready-not-firing-on-ipad) that might helpful to sort it out.

Comment: @AyanSengupta Thanks but that is about autoplaying videos, not about playlists on iPad. The approach has the same problems because I have 2 sites, one using the Javascript API and the other using the iframe embeds and both are not working on iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There few bugs on YT iFrame player on iOS. Hopefully, they are all going to be resolved soon. You can track them all in issue tracker. Here's the main one.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5204&q=API%3DYouTube%20iOS&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything specifically related to playlists? In my case I am just using the `<iframe>` method so no fancy Javascript stuff. The only difference I have between a working one and mine is that the working one is a single video URL and the non-working one is a playlist.

Comment: Seems like there are some bugs related to playlists too :( https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5397&q=API%3DYouTube%20iOS&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: They are all filed internally, we hope to have them all fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't add a comment so had to add an answer.

It appears they have fixed the issue at their end, see latest updates here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/_crm-T7BFvM/_V2xDBrV0HcJ

Comment: Thanks. Yes just received the notification. I am waiting for some of the other users to verify it has been fixed before doing any updates because I don't have access to an iOS device at the moment.